# Manipulating variables outside SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum +1 AS rank, 
    round(LAT_N,4) as lat 
FROM STATION 
HAVING rank = CEIL(@rowCount/2) 
ORDER BY LAT_N
```

How can I not show the rank? Or how can I manipulate/assign variables outside select?

Comment: What version of MySQL? Probably really easy to make a view and then select the columns you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT lat
FROM (SELECT @rownum := @rownum +1 AS rank, 
            round(LAT_N,4) as lat 
      FROM STATION CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rownum := 0) params
      ORDER BY lat_n
     ) s
WHERE rank = CEIL(@rowCount / 2) ;
```

Note that in more recent versions of MySQL, you might need to do the sort in a subquery.